# Grails. Upload files to temp folder and display them in gsp

Tags: java, grails, groovy, upload, multipart

My intention is to upload images and store them in a temp folder. Then I want to display these images in the .gsp views. The process I've been trying to make it to work is something like this:

First, upload the file from input:

```
<input id="inputImg" type="file" accept="image/*">
```

Create the file:

```
def saveFile(MultipartFile inputImg) {

    def contentType = inputImg.getContentType()
    def originalFilename = inputImg.getOriginalFilename()
    def extension = FilenameUtils.getExtension(originalFilename)

    String tempPath = System.getProperty("java.io.tmpdir") + "/uploads"

    File file = new File("$tempPath/$originalFilename")
    FileUtils.forceMkdirParent(file)
    inputImg.transferTo(file)

    if (contentType == 'application/octet-stream') {
        contentType = MimeTypeUtils.getContentTypeByFileName(originalFilename)
    }

    Path filePath = Paths.get(file.toString())
    Path path = Paths.get(tempPath)
    Path relativePath = path.relativize(filePath)

    Avatar avatar = new Avatar(
            path: relativePath.toString(),
            contentType: contentType,
            name: originalFilename,
            extension: extension
    )
}
```

Once is stored in the temp folder, I found this solution but I'm not sure if it's the best way to do it. I'm trying to process the image with base64 encoding before sending it to the view:

```
def filename = user?.avatar?.name
def file = new File("$tempPath/$filename")
def base64file = file?.readBytes()?.encodeBase64()
```

And finally show it in the gsp:

```
<img alt="img" src="data:image/*;base64,${base64file}"/>
```

I would like to know if there is another best way to do this process, I don't know if I'm missing something or if this isn't a good procedure to manage with files and images...

Comment: Not an answer to your question but just FYI... Instead of doing the `java.io.tmpdir` thing and `new File("$tempPath/$originalFilename")` you can use the method that is provided by `java.io.File` so you can simply call `File.createTempFile('prefix value goes here', 'suffix value goes here')`.  See https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/File.html#createTempFile-java.lang.String-java.lang.String- .

Comment: Thanks @Jeff Scott Brown, I'll try that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using the inline images with Base64 encoding which is good for displaying relatively small images (up to 5k). The advantage of this approach is that you dump the page WITH images in a single HTTP-connection.

If the images grow considerably larger (> 1MB), then you can not use caching and other nice features, so you have to send the data over the line over and over again and that would slow down user experience.

Another way would be to deliver each image in a separate request.

You could define a controller action like:

```
class ImageController {

  def image(String id){
    def file = new File("$tempPath/$id")
    if( !file.exists() )
      render status: 404
    else{
      response.contentType  = 'image/jpeg'
      response.withOutputStream{ it << file.readBytes() }
    }
  }
}
```

then in your GSP you put:

```
<img alt="img" src="${g.createLink( controller:'image', action:'image', id:user.avatar.name )}"/>
```

Comment: Thank you @injecteer, did this and I think it's a better solution since I don't know the image sizes I'm going to handle. Works perfect, the only thing I've changed was the last line, I did "response.outputStream.write(file.readBytes())" instead.